# Intel avx ymm float to integer conversion

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, simd

I read four double-precision 64-bit (qword) floats from memory into ymm1:

```
vmovupd ymm1,[r11+r15]
```

Now I want an instruction that converts them to integer.  I tried the following:

```
VCVTTPD2UQQ ymm0,ymm1

OR

VCVTTSD2SI ymm0,ymm1
```

Both instructions assemble and link, but both crash at runtime.

All of my research points to these two instructions.  Is there a different instruction I haven't found yet to convert four qword floats to qword integer in ymm registers?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The first is AVX512 (you can tell because it's doing packed double <-> 64-bit integer when AVX2 and earlier only have HW support for packed conversion to/from 32-bit integers).  The 2nd isn't valid because it's `sd` (scalar double) with a ymm destination, not an integer reg like RAX. With NASM:  `foo.asm:1: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands`.

Comment: Is there an instruction that will convert four floats in ymm to four integers to ymm?  I can do it in four separate instructions using pinsrq, but I would like to do it with a single instruction, which I haven't found yet.

Comment: No, there isn't.  AVX2 and earlier only have *packed* conversions to/from 32-bit integers, even for `double`.  But fortunately  a search for `site:stackoverflow.com double to 64-bit integer avx` found Mysticial's answer right away which explains all this.

Comment: That helps.  He's using intrinsics, but I can translate.

Comment: Updated Mysticial's answer on the linked duplicate to state clearly that single-instruction support was new in AVX512.  Note that I think he's converting with round-to-nearest, not truncation, so watch out for that.